# moved libc.so and libc.so.6 to my /home/ dir. Can I move them back to /lib/ using a live Ubuntu image?

Tags: glibc, libc

I stupidly moved the **libc.so** and **libc.so.6** files to my **/home/** dir. I thought I could replace them with a newer version that I compiled under **/home/glibc/build** but, of course, I then realised that no commands work, nor sudo either. The files are there, they are not deleted or altered, they were 'just' moved out of **/lib/** and into my **/home/**.

So, my question is if this can be reversed using a live CD? I mean use sudo via the live distro and run the mv command to bring the original files to their proper destination?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, a live CD should allow you to fix this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimRoberts. So, if I move the original files back to /lib/ will everything work normally again?

Comment: I can't make promises, but if that's all you did, then putting things back should fix it.

Comment: yes, I did not delete the originals and I did not uninstall the libc library, like with apt-get or something... I moved them out of the /lib/ folder in a (stupid) attempt to replace them with the custom-built ones..

Comment: Updating system GLIBC is a really bad idea in general. You should read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617